# Como obter o valor da classe de uma div que está dentro de um RepeaterItem?

Tags: javascript, c#, html

Abaixo o código simplificado:
Comportamento atual

1. Ao Clicar na "divOnoff", a classe da div "divAtivoOnOff" alterna o valor a cada click entre "OnOff on" e "OnOff off".
Como guardar esse valor no HiddenOnOff?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptModulos" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RptModulos_ItemDataBound"> 
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdModulo" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate> 
            <div class="OnOff off" id="divAtivoOnOff" runat="server">
            <asp:HiddenField id="HiddenOnOff" runat="server" value="off" ></asp:HiddenField>
            <div class="control-on-off">
                    <span class="lbl-off">INATIVO</span>

                    <div id="divOnoff" class="on-off">
                        <span class="interruptor"></span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="lbl-on">ATIVO</span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode user o  para ser acionada quando houver alguma alteração e depois usar o  para setar o novo valor.

```
$('.divAtivoOnOff').change(function(){
     $('#HiddenOnOff').val(novoValor);    
});
```

Obs.: coloquei novoValor pois não entendi qual elemento exatamente será alterado e qual atributo. Se for por exemplo na classe interruptor pode usar o seguinte para obter o valor: $(".interruptor").text();